# Building Android: No Rule to make target

Tags: android, build, makefile

I am currently building SE Android 4.2.1_r1 on Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit. I am almost through the make process, but I am currently stuck on the following error.

```
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/commons-cli-1.2.jar
host Prebuilt: commons-codec-1.4 (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/commons-codec-   
1.4_intermediates/javalib.jar)
Notice file: prebuilts/tools/common/http-client/NOTICE -- out/host/linux
x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//framework/commons-codec-1.4.jar.txt
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/commons-codec-1.4.jar
host Prebuilt: commons-compress-1.0 (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/commons
compress-1.0_intermediates/javalib.jar)
Notice file: prebuilts/tools/common/commons-compress/NOTICE -- out/host/linux
x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//framework/commons-compress-1.0.jar.txt
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/commons-compress-1.0.jar
host Prebuilt: commons-logging-1.1.1 (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/commons
logging-1.1.1_intermediates/javalib.jar)
Notice file: prebuilts/tools/common/http-client/NOTICE -- out/host/linux
x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//framework/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar.txt
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
Notice file: libcore/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//framework/core
hostdex.jar.txt
host Prebuilt: tzdata-host (out/host/linux-x86/obj/ETC/tzdata-host_intermediates/tzdata)
Install: out/host/linux-x86/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/core-hostdex.jar
Notice file: external/junit/NOTICE -- out/host/linux
x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//framework/core-junit-hostdex.jar.txt
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/core-junit-hostdex.jar
host Java: sqlite-jdbc-host (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sqlite-jdbc
host_intermediates/classes)
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
make: *** No rule to make target `out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/mockwebserver
hostdex_intermediates/javalib.jar', needed by `out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-   
tests-hostdex_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar'.  Stop.
```

I tried to google my error, but I am not sure that anyone has actually successfully built SE Android 4.2.1. The directory mockwebserver-hostdex_intermediates does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to get rid of the error.

In libcore/JavaLibrary.mk (line 155) change mockwebserver-hostdex to mockwebserver-host

It is a bug in the AOSP. Until they fix it, this will work.

Source (in one of the comments): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/o8Qg4CVrN70/fR0OOu9xAZcJ

Answer (score 1):

I´m having the same issues compiling Android-4.2.1 from Master repo so I suspect that it´s not a problem from SEandroid. I have been sucesfully compiled SEandroid about two days ago in the same VM with the same config (lunch all-eng).

I can´t find any information related to this problem , just a few people with the same problem but without any solution.

Comment: so you didn't run into this issue? could you tell me what parameters you used and what device you were building for?

Comment: In both cases I used the same config, full-eng && make, for the emulator. I find quite strange that I could compile seandroid and not android, waiting for some advice to get it works.

Comment: find: `src': No such file or directory

Were you able to fix this?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/o8Qg4CVrN70/fR0OOu9xAZcJ

Forum I found that has some solutions on it; trying the solutions now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem with JDK and improper environment setup. Make sure you have installed proper JDK for Android KK [Java JDK6]. Similar problem I faced in Android Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you got OpenJDK 7 installed and you done.

Install OpenJDK 7 from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16263651/3621912