# Installing Java 7 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation

> **Note:** This question was asked before Oracle made the OpenJDK the free version of the Oracle JDK, and the historic answers reflect that.  As of 2022 you should not use Java 7 unless you must for projects which cannot run on OpenJDK 8.

To install java I have always used the classic way from the terminal.
I would like to install java manually.
I placed the folder of the JDK on the desk and I set environment variables (PATH, CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME).
From the terminal, if I type `java -version` I get printed

```
foralobo@ubuntu-vincy:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

But when I try to install eclipse or netbeans, the system warns by saying that there is no java installed on the machine.

What is missing to compleatare manual installation?
(Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: I think you had to run `update-alternatives` to inform ubuntu where its "new" java installation resides.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/173951/11547

Comment: [On AskUbuntu, I answered how to install Java 7 or 8 on a more recent Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161572/830570).
This answer also solves the "PPA DISCONTINUED" Problem.

Answer (score 551, accepted):

> This answer used to describe how to install Oracle Java 7. This no longer works since Oracle end-of-lifed Java 7 and put the binary downloads for versions with security patches behind a paywall. Also, OpenJDK has grown up and is a more viable alternative nowadays.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and higher, Java 7 is no longer available. Usually you're best off installing Java 8 (or 9) instead.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

or, f you also want the compiler, get the jdk:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

In Trusty, the easiest way to install Java 7 currently is to install OpenJDK package:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

or, for the jdk:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

If you are specifically looking for Java 7 on a version of Ubuntu that no longer supports it, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-or-higher .

Comment: Added @brent-robinson 's tip on how to set the environment variables. Thanks Brent!

Comment: after installing oracle-java7-set-default, I was not able to echo $JAVA_HOME. Hence set $JAVA_HOME manually in .bashrc

Comment: @sumitramteke I suspect you'd have to start a new session before the environment settings take effect.

Comment: It's me or the first command it's wrong :P it should be apt-add-repository shouldn't it?

Comment: @pekechis both work, apt-add-repository is a symlink to add-apt-repository. Says here it got added in 11.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38021/how-to-add-a-ppa-on-a-server

Comment: @flup : Sorry I'm new with _Ubuntu_. Will you please elaborate more with your comment in regards of **starting new session**.

Comment: @sumitramteke I mean to log out and in again. The enviroment variables are set when you log in.

Comment: @flup : Ok, yeah but that thing has already being tested. Still not able to echo the same.

Comment: @sumitramteke then you can set `JAVA_HOME` manually by adding `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` to `/etc/environment`

Comment: Yes, done the same. @flup thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: If you want to remove all non-Oracle Java packages before installing, use this command: `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\* icedtea-\* icedtea6-\*`

Comment: If `add-apt-repository` is missing, run `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275856/auto-yes-to-the-license-agreement-on-sudo-apt-get-y-install-oracle-java7-instal to automatically accept the license agreement.

Comment: No longer works. Oracle seems to have removed the binaries. See my answer below.

Comment: I always get connection failure when downloading this. It appears the link to site has been move. Any idea where I could still get JDK 7? I am planning to install Android Studio and this frickin software needs it even though I have JDK 8 installed

Comment: On AskUbuntu, there also were some deprecated answers, so I answered [how to install Java 7 or 8 on a more recent Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161572/830570). This answer also solves the "PPA DISCONTINUED" Problem.
You can also consider [this link](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8_java/precise/main/base/oracle-java7-set-default) to set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` as [Brent Robinson mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20565550/4575793).

Answer (score 56):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

and if you already have other JDK versions installed

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

then select the Java 7 version.

Comment: ITYM "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk"

Comment: this is the simplest solution, and doesn't involve adding extra repos.

Comment: The choice is between the openjdk and the version provided by Oracle.

Answer (score 48):

In addition to flup's answer you might also want to run the following to set JAVA_HOME and PATH:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
```

More information at:
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8_java/precise/main/base/oracle-java7-set-default

Comment: please add this as a comment to @flup answer

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment on other peoples answers yet

Comment: Link to [@flup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16263651/4575793) - the edit queue was full unfortunately.

Answer (score 38):

> **Note:** According to comments this text was copied from a GIST without attribution.

Download java `jdk<version>-linux-x64.tar.gz` file from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.

Extract  this file where you want. like: `/home/java`(Folder name created by user in home directory).

Now open terminal.
Set path `JAVA_HOME=path` of your jdk folder(open jdk folder then right click on any folder, go to properties then copy the path using select all)
and paste here.

Like: `JAVA_HOME=/home/xxxx/java/JDK1.8.0_201`

Let Ubuntu know where our JDK/JRE is located.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /home/xxxx/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java 20000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /home/xxxx/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javac 20000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /home/xxxx/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javaws 20000
```

Tell Ubuntu that our installation i.e., jdk1.8.0_05 must be the default Java.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java /home/xxxx/sipTest/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /home/xxxx/java/sipTest/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /home/xxxxx/sipTest/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javaws
```

Now try:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing `/usr/bin/java`).

```
  Selection    Path                                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle1/bin/java   1047      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.6                       1046      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle1/bin/java   1047      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java      1         manual mode
```

Press enter to keep the current choice [`*`], or type selection number: 3

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
```

Repeat the above for:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

Comment: I saw this text on a GIST, was this yours or copy/pasted?

Comment: copy/pasted here as I did not find any of the above working :)

Comment: Default Java or from repo couldn't be installed but It worked, solved problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti If this was copied and pasted from somewhere else, I think it should be better to add a sentence explicitly saying so, with a link to the original source.

Comment: @lfurini:I already mentioned it if you read all the comments...I don't have the original link...The reason I added here is.. so that it could be useful for the rest and they need not have to spend time in searching it...As like I have invested to much time in getting the right steps...don't want others to invest time in such things..

Answer (score 12):

I think you should consider Java installation procedure carefully. Following is the detailed process which covers almost all possible failures.

Installing Java with **apt-get** is easy. First, update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, check if Java is not already installed:

```
java -version
```

If it returns "The program java can be found in the following packages", Java hasn't been installed yet, so execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

**You are fine till now as I assume.**

This will install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). If you instead need the Java Development Kit (JDK), which is usually needed to compile Java applications (for example Apache Ant, Apache Maven, Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

**That is everything that is needed to install Java.**

**Installing OpenJDK 7:**

To install OpenJDK 7, execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

This will install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). If you instead need the Java Development Kit (JDK), execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

**Installing Oracle JDK:**

The Oracle JDK is the official JDK; however, it is no longer provided by Oracle as a default installation for Ubuntu.

You can still install it using apt-get. To install any version, first execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, depending on the version you want to install, execute one of the following commands:

**Oracle JDK 7:**

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

**Oracle JDK 8:**

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 4):

PPA method no longer works.

> While Oracle Java 6 and 7 are not supported for quite a while, they were still available for download on Oracle's website until recently.
>
> However, the binaries were removed about 10 days ago (?), so the Oracle Java (JDK) 6 and 7 installers available in the WebUpd8 Oracle Java PPA no longer work.
>
> Oracle Java 6 and 7 are now only available for those with an Oracle Support account (which is not free), so I can't support this for the PPA packages.

Source : http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html
Dated : June 2017

[Oracle's download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) says

> Updates for Java SE 7 released after April 2015, and updates for Java SE 6 released after April 2013 are only available to Oracle Customers through My Oracle Support (requires support login).
>
> Java SE Advanced offers users commercial features, access to critical bug fixes, security fixes, and general maintenance".

I had to download it from Oracle archives -
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

You need an account for this though.

Comment: This is correct, however, I got it fully working with Abhijit Bashetti answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28874505/2161698

Answer (score 3):

Oracle as well as modern versions of Ubuntu have moved to newer versions of Java.  The default for Ubuntu 20.04 is OpenJDK 11 which is good enough for most purposes.

If you really need it for running legacy programs, OpenJDK 8 is also available for Ubuntu 20.04 from the official repositories.

If you *really* need exactly Java 7, the best bet as of 2020 is to download a Zulu distribution.  The easiest to install if you have root privileges is the .DEB version, otherwise download the .ZIP one.

https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-7-lts&os=ubuntu&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk#download-openjdk

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle Java 1.7.0 from .deb packages

```
wget https://raw.github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/master/oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh -7
sudo apt-get update
sudo sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk oracle-java7-fonts oracle-java7-source 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

### Workaround for 1.7.0_51

There is an [Issue 123](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/issues/123) currently in OAB and a [pull request](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/pull/125)

Here is the patched vesion:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/ladios/oab-java6/master/oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh -7
sudo apt-get update
sudo sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk oracle-java7-fonts oracle-java7-source 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

[flup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263556/installing-java-7-on-ubuntu?answertab=active#tab-top) is the best but it did not work for me completely. I had to do the following as well to get it working:

1. `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/`
2. `chmod 777` on the folder
3. `./gradlew build` - Building Hibernate

Comment: 777 is a bad idea in general as others can alter your build environment.  Be certain you are the only user of the machine.

Answer (score -1):

```
Open Applicaction -> Accessories -> Terminal

Type commandline as below...

sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

Type commandline as below...

apt-cache search jdk

(Note: openjdk-7-jdk is symbolically used here. You can choose the JDK version as per your requirement.)

For "JAVA_HOME" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path...

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk

(Note: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk" is symbolically used here just for demostration. You should use your path as per your installation.)

For "PATH" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path...

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/bin

(Note: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk" is symbolically used here just for demostration. You should use your path as per your installation.)

Check for "open jdk" installation, just type command in "Terminal" as shown below

javac -version
```