# My openjdk-7-jdk is out of date

Tags: ubuntu, java

I am running ubuntu 12.04 LTS. because  my Java program is going to use the method getSystemCpuLoad(), I need java-1.7.0, but the current version is 1.6.0_31 My typing of

> $ java -version
>   gives:
>   java version "1.6.0_31" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3)
>   (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2) OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.25-b01,
>   mixed mode, sharing)

What do I do?
   I found no wy  to download a newer openjdk for Ubuntu, upon visiting openjdk.java.net/install/

Comment: YOu get what you get with open source.  You're free to write your own.

Comment: Sorry?What  do you  mean?

Comment: People who write open source software are volunteers.  They don't produce it on a schedule or demand.  If you can't find what you need, you can always volunteer to contribute.  There are JDK 7 details here: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7u/

Comment: Do you mean there is no way  to upgrade my openjdk?  I am not that expert a programmer as to start writing compiler code.

Comment: If there isn't one available for your OS, I think the answer is "no".  I'd be surprised to find out that there was no current JDK available for Ubuntu.  Look further afield.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Java 7 on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263556/installing-java-7-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides releases of [Java 8 for Ubuntu 12 & 13](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) for both 32-bit and 64-bit machines.

[This tutorial from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get) explains how to install both OpenJDK and Oracle JDK on Ubuntu 12 with various options.

This question, [Installing Java 7 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16263556/642706), has multiple answers.