# HTTP ERROR 404 while installing java 7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-14.04, apt

I am trying to install java 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 following the instructions at [Installing Java 7 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263556/installing-java-7-on-ubuntu/16263651#16263651) .

When I try to install java 7, I get a HTTP 404 ERROR.

**Does anybody know if installing java 7 using these instructions is still supported?**

**Am I missing something that is obvious to everybody else and not to me‽**

*Thank you in advance for advice.*

I executed the following commands as per the instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Here is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java7-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u67+7u60arm-0~webupd8~4) ...
Please report to author unsupported platform 'ppc64'.
Proceeding without web browser plugin support
Please report to author unsupported platform 'ppc64'.
Proceeding without web browser plugin support
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-09-01 16:26:08--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/
jdk-7u60-linux-.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.62.6.106, 23.62.6.153
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.62.6.106|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/jdk-7u60-linux-.tar.gz [following]
--2014-09-01 16:26:09--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/jdk-7u60-linux-.tar.gz
--2014-09-01 16:26:09--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/jdk-7u60-linux-.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 96.16.150.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|96.16.150.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/jdk-7u60-linux-.tar.gz?AuthParam=1409603301_59d736536b051796a298904fd90f70bd [following]
--2014-09-01 16:26:09--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/jdk-7u60-linux-.tar.gz?AuthParam=1409603301_59d736536b051796a298904fd90f70bd
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.62.6.106|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-09-01 16:26:10 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt-get installing oracle java 7 stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142450/apt-get-installing-oracle-java-7-stopped-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 404 error meaning page not found. It looks like though the connection was established package manager could not download the `tar.gz` file.

If it is some internal error from oracles site retry should so it. However if you are behind some proxy that is not allowing this transfer there is not much you can do.

Either way try doing

> wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/jdk-7u60-linux-.tar.gz?AuthParam=1409603301_59d736536b051796a298904fd90f70bd

and see if you can download the file.

Comment: No proxies involved. I tried your command and received a `403 Forbidden` error. I have tried installing java 6 as well and get the same `404` error. Multiple tries on the install. Perhaps I will have to wait if it's an error at download.oracle.com. Thank you for you input.