# Java -version error

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

I have installed JDK 1.8 on my ubuntu 16.04, for some kind of work I had to install JDK 1.7.I installed it without did anything to my older version and changed the $JAVA_HOME to point the newly installed location.

echo `$JAVA_HOME` works fine , showing newly installed version which is 1.7

but when I do `$ java -version` it shows earlier installed version which is 1.8.

*Why does this happen? How to resolve it.*

I need 1.7 to work with it further.

**If I went wrong in somewhere please correct me,I need good explanation regarding this.**

Thank you.
here is my terminal

[image: terminal]

Comment: You need to set the PATH. JAVA_HOME is irrelevant.

Comment: I have put these lines in bashrc                                                              #JAVA HOME directory setup
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_79
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

Comment: in case you installed your java's from the [webupd8 ppa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16263651/995891) also installed the `oracle-java7-set-default` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run following command in terminal:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

It shows installed alternatives for `java` command. You can choose which one you will use by default further on.

Comment: could you be able explain this further to me?

Comment: `update-alternatives` updates the links in /etc/alternatives to point the command to the actual program to run.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/233190/what-exactly-does-update-alternatives-do